# Function Space and Hölder Inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let the measure space $([0,1],\mathbb{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ be given ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$). Given $f\in L^p$ (so $\int |f|^p d\lambda < \infty$), show that if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/q} \int_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} |f| d\lambda = 0  $$ My progress so far: $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/q} \int_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} |f| d\lambda \leq ||f||_p$ and thus bounded. I can show this by the Holder Inequality, which I think must be a part of the solution. But of course is boundedness not nearly enough. Could someone give a hint (not a solution!) how I need to proceed/approach this question?

Comment: Consider the functions $f_m \colon x \mapsto f(x)\cdot \chi_{[0,1/m]}(x)$.

Comment: I thought of that and then I can show that: $$\int_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} |f| d\lambda = \int |f| \cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x) d\lambda \leq ||f||_p \cdot (\int |\chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)|^q d\lambda)^{\frac{1}{q}} = ||f||_p \cdot (\int |\chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)| d\lambda)^{\frac{1}{q}} = ||f||_p \cdot (\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ (I used Holder). That is how I showed boundedness, but it doesn't prove the claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the computation you made in your coment, use $\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ twice instead of once:

$$\int_0^{1/n} \lvert f\rvert\,d\lambda = \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,1/n]}\cdot \lvert f\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}\rvert\,d\lambda \leqslant \lVert \chi_{[0,1/n]}\rVert_q \lVert f\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}\rVert_p = n^{-1/q}\lVert f\cdot\chi_{[0,1/n]}\rVert_p.$$

By the dominated convergence theorem, $f\cdot\chi_{[0,1/n]} \to 0$ in $L^p$.